# Smart contract upgrade timeout on hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts, hyperledger-chaincode

When upgrading a smart contract the following error occurs:

Failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc", error: timeout expired while starting chaincode couponcontract:8 for transaction

As this is an lscc error could anyone help on how to debug or identify what is causing it to break?

[image]

API version:

"dependencies": {
        "fabric-contract-api": "~1.4.0",
        "fabric-shim": "~1.4.0"
    },

Environment:
aws t2.micro

Comment: I would like to understand why it was downvoted. It is a pertinent question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
As the hole network was installed in the same t2.micro instance, the process was consuming all the CPU when upgrading a contract. So, it was breaking duo the time elapsed was causing a timeout.
I changed it to a t2.Medium(2 cpu) and now it is working like a charm!!

Answer (score 1):

Your chaincode is likely taking too long to start / launch.  Try increasing `CORE_CHAINCODE_EXECUTETIMEOUT`.  The default is `30s` so try increasing to `60s`.

Comment: Thanks @gari-singh, I've tried as you mentioned, but found the same error. :(